# Можно ли конвертировать тип string в формат bool в C#?

Tags: c#, конвертация

Нужно что бы когда пользователь вводит в консоль слово "YES" оно конвертировалось в тип данных bool = true, как это можно грамотно реализовать на C#?

Comment: `var myBool = myString == "YES"` ?

Comment: или, напрмер, var myBool = myString.ToUpper() == "YES";

Answer (score 1):

```
// string input = ...
string[] ss = new string[] { "yes", "y", "да", "д" };
bool b = ss.Contains(input.ToLower());
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Не компилируется. Пожалуста, проверяйте код перед публикацией. Ошибки в 2 из 3 строк кода.

Comment: @aepot ``using namespace std;`` ?

Comment: Нет. Если студии нет под рукой, можете проверить на sharplab.io или dotnetfiddle.

Comment: @aepot ну я как минимум только вторую строку вставил в sharplab.io - и она внезапно компилируется.

Comment: Сдаюсь, я с `Any` перепутал.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать этот вариант:

```
private bool GetBoolValue(string str)
{
   return str == "yes";
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]